# How to disable single event in mysql

Tags: mysql, events

I have created some events in mysql for auto schedule running procedure , now i want to disable few events from them. Please help me with the prpper mysql query to disable the events.

Comment: Please spend at least 5-10 minutes searching Stack Overflow before posting.  All questions posted need to show some effort of research in order to get help.

Comment: Thanks Tim, but i did not get the result while searching by above topic hence you have found duplicate question..Sorry